# I started downloading MacKeeper, but can't quit the download — what should I do?

Tags: macos, virus

I saw MacKeeper on a link to download something and it said it would clean your computer for you. I started downloading it and halfway through I searched "Is MacKeeper a virus?" What I found told me that MacKeeper was a virus and I shouldn't download it.

I tried getting rid of the installer but I couldn't. I even went to the Dock and pressed *Quit* but it didn't work.

It was nearly finished downloading at this point. So I resorted to the option of switching my Mac off using the power button on the Mac itself. It was still downloading, so I do not know if it's safe to go back onto my computer.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you just download a file called `MacKeeper.pkg` or similar, or did you actually double click this file and continued through the installer?

Comment: Double clicked the file.

Comment: And did you click through the installer, or…? To which step exactly did you proceed?

Comment: Oh, the installer I did and got to the 3rd step which was installing it I think.

Comment: You should simply remove it like any other application on [OS X](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3255417?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: @Ramhound The OP quit the installation process, so chances are it's not even installed properly.

Comment: @slhck - I am not even sure the author knows what was installed or not installed. Since OS X handles installation of an application a great deal differently than Windows, the installation being incomplete might not be important, considering the uninstallation process is simply moving the files to the trash.

Answer (score 2):

First off, don't panic. It's not actually a virus, it's just a useless program, totally overpriced, with very shady advertisement tactics.

This may sound weird, but I think the best idea would be to fully install MacKeeper, then remove it using the official instructions. If you aborted the installation half way through, chances are that it will not uninstall properly.

So, click through the installer until it's finished. Quit MacKeeper. Then go to *Applications* (press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in Finder), find the *MacKeeper* icon, and drag it to the Trash.

You should be prompted for your password. After entering that, another window should pop up, where you can click *Uninstall*.

[image]

It's also asking you why you want to uninstall MacKeeper, but this seems optional.

There are various sources that explain how to uninstall it:

- [This Apple discussion post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22927956#22927956)
- [Official uninstallation instructions](http://help.mackeeper.zeobit.com/Manual/GettingStarted/UninstallingMacKeeper.html)
- [Softonic instructions](http://support.softonic.com/index.php?/english/Knowledgebase/Article/View/437/39/how-to-uninstall-mackeeper)

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the file, but didn't execute/open it, you should be able to simply toss the file into the trash, and your computer should be safe from the threat.

If you successfully downloaded the file and proceeded with the installation, I would recommend **immediately** deleting the .app file and any other file it produced (if it produced any) and running an antivirus. The App Store hosts a large variety of popular antiviruses for OS X, such as  [ClamXav](http://www.clamxav.com/) or Bitdefender.

**EDIT**: This post was made under the presumption that MacKeeper is in fact a *malicious software*.